# Can Cocoa radio buttons that do not use NSMatrix have bindings?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, binding, radio-button, nsmatrix

On a previous project I used an NSMatrix object to implement three radio buttons. I did not have an action tied to these buttons, they were bound to an @property so that when a different radio button was chosen, the property's value changed.

Now I want to add another one of these choosers, but NSMatrix has been eliminated. I can add the buttons just fine, but now I must (must I?) attach them to a -action and change the property manually with something like [self setProperty: [sender tag]];

Using bindings seemed a better approach to me since I did not have to have the -action method or the statement to assign the value of the property.

Is there a way to use bindings within the new paradigm of NSMatrix being deprecated?

Answer (score 0):

This a five years old question, but since it shows in results, here is a simple trick : binding two individual radio buttons to a same boolean property does work. One need to have the NSNegateBoolean value transformer.
Using more radio button should be possible also by adding a custom value transformer.